# Issue in asterisk server

Tags: asterisk

I tried to enter Date Of Birth as `11211971` through my phone, but IVR (Interactive Voice Response) has `11121197`.

please tell anybody what is the root cause for this issue

It is my code

```
exten => s,n,Read(dateofbirth,${ANOUNCEMENT_RECORDINGS}/HIP-5A1,8,s)        
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${dateofbirth}" = ""]?retry-dateofbirth-notentered)
exten => s,n,Set(monthofbirth=${dateofbirth:0:2})
exten => s,n,Set(dayofbirth=${dateofbirth:2:2})
exten => s,n,Set(yearofbirth=${dateofbirth:4:4}) 
exten => s,n,Goto(${IF($[$[${LEN(${monthofbirth})} != 2]|$[${monthofbirth} > 12] |$["${monthofbirth}" ="00"]|$["${monthofbirth}" ="**"]|$[${LEN(${dayofbirth})}!=2]|$[${dayofbirth} > 31]|$["${dayofbirth}" ="00"]|$["${dayofbirth}" ="**"]|$[${LEN(${yearofbirth})} !=4]|$["${yearofbirth}" ="0000"]|$["${yearofbirth}" ="****"]]?retry-dateofbirth-invalid:saydateofbirth)})
```

Comment: can you give any more details? how are you reading the digits? can show some code? have you configured asterisk to receive dtmf's as info, rfc, or inband?

Comment: What channel driver?  SIP, DAHDI, IAX2?

Comment: I have used SIP channel driver

Comment: please tell anybody root cause for this issue

Comment: What version of asterisk?  DTMF handling has changed significantly from 1.4 to 1.6.x to 1.8.x so it's possible you are using a buggy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is if you are caling from DID and entering DTMF there might be some problem with DTMF receiving or DTMF negotiations in asterisk side you need to put relaxdtmf=yes , rfc2833compensate=yes and dtmfmode=rfc2833 if your provider support it.

if you are calling from softphone then try to enable dtmf type in softphone or sip hard phone.